# Create firewalls for Azure Synapse Workspace when Public Network Access is Disabled?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-synapse

I am trying to provision Synapse Workspace with terraform(with public network access disabled). The synapse workspaces are created and status is succeeded too. Most of the resources are created/provisioned successfully.

However, I also would like to add/create firewall rules on the Synapse workspace. I noticed on Portal that when the Public Network Access is Disabled, you can't create or modify firewalls. Also that is the error I get when I tried to add firewalls on the synapse workspace with terraform.

```
Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code='PublicNetworkAccessDenied' Message='Unable to create or modify firewall rules when public network interface for the Synapse Workspace is disabled. To manage firewall rules, please enable the public network access.'
```

So if need to add firewalls to the workspace, do I need to enable the public network access?
If so I will update my terraform code to set Public Network Access to True.

Actually when I tried to enable Public Network Access via Portal and save it, it said Deployment failed, so it failed and state went from Succeeded to Failed and it said check Deployment for more information. But I couldn't find information about that given deployment anywhere. With Failed status, I can't create firewalls, as Terraform complains workspace is in failed status. So I recreated the workspace again via Terraform with public network access disabled, now the workspaces are in succeeded state.

Would it work if via Terraform(as via Portal it failed) we update Public Network Access to True? Would the Workspace state be Succeeded after updating to True?

What if it fails to update the public network access to True? Synapse workspace would go to Failed state and then I can't do anything with the provisioning with Terraform. As Terraform would complain that the workspace isn't in Succeeded state or it is in failed state.
In the case the workspace goes to failed status, how can I correct it to make it Succeeded?

Please suggest the best solution forward.

In short, I want to add/create firewall rules to my Synapse workspace via Terraform. I am unable to, as the public network access is disabled for the given workspace.

Thank you for your help.

---

Update: I can remove the code that adds or modifies firewall rules, which needs workspace to be public access enabled. Because I want my Synapse workspace to have public network access as disabled always. So adding firewall rules doesn't make sense.

But I also get the below error when I try to provision Synapse with public network access disabled. I have few role assignments for Synapse and they failed with the below error. My understanding is that the agent that runs this pipeline isn't having access to this Synapse workspace, because it is public and the created synapse is private? My pipelines are running on a self hosted agents.

```
│ Error: listing synapse role definitions accesscontrol.RoleDefinitionsClient#ListRoleDefinitions: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="PublicNetworkAccessDenied" Message="The public network interface on this Workspace is not accessible. To connect to this Workspace, use the Private Endpoint from inside your virtual network or enable public network access for this workspace."
│ 
│   with module.synapse.azurerm_synapse_role_assignment.this["synapse-administrator"],
│   on .terraform/modules/synapse/rbac.tf, in resource "azurerm_synapse_role_assignment" "this":
│  resource "azurerm_synapse_role_assignment" "this" {
│
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment .***

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "example" {
  name                                 = "kaexamplesynapse"
  resource_group_name                  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                             = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.id
  sql_administrator_login              = "sqladminuser"
  sql_administrator_login_password     = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  public_network_access_enabled   =  false

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

[image]

With below code:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "adlsexamplestorageacc"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_kind             = "StorageV2"
  is_hns_enabled           = "true"
}


resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
  name               = "default"
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "example" {
  name                                 = "kaexamplesynapse"
  resource_group_name                  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                             = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.id
  sql_administrator_login              = "xxx"
  sql_administrator_login_password     = "xxx!"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_synapse_firewall_rule" "example" {
  name                 = "AllowAll"
  synapse_workspace_id = azurerm_synapse_workspace.example.id
  start_ip_address     = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address       = "255.255.255.255"
}
```

I could create the firewall rule to azure synapse workspace successfully .

[image]

Note:

- **Selecting the Disable  for public network won’t allow any firewall rules to configure.**
- From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/664868/azure-synapse-disable-public-network-access.html If Synapse public network access is disabled , you may have to use  **`"self-hosted"`** agent as Microsoft hosted agents will  fail  as you may already  have
  some pipelines that configure Synapse, like Synapse roles or Managed private endpoints.

Comment: Thanks, Kavya for taking time to answer my questions. Much appreciated! I have a few follow up questions.
1. I understood that firewall rules and public network access are mutually-exclusive. 2. Even if I could skip firewall rules there are other resources which are failing due to public network access.

Comment: Please check for an update on the question at the end. When I try to provision synapse workspace with public network access disabled, even the role assignments are failing as the agent(I believe) isn't not able to connect to the workspace to make any changes. I have posted the full error in my question at the end.